# How to assign each value for each index in flutter

Tags: ios, flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I m making an app which display a row of images ( All of them using loop / index from 0-4). The code :

```
for (int i = 0; i <= 3; i++)
     child: Card(
                          semanticContainer: true,
                          clipBehavior: Clip.antiAliasWithSaveLayer,
                          child: Container(
                            width: 300,
                            height: 300,
                            color: Colors.accents[i],
                            child: Image.asset(
                              "assets/farCryImages/$i.jpg",
                              alignment: Alignment.center,
                              fit: BoxFit.cover,
                            ),
                          ),
                          shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8),
                          ),
                          elevation: 5,
                        ),
```

And i wanted to show the user a popup of their name ( i.e : first picture : a , second picture : b etc..). But i can't seem to find a way to do it and I need help.

I tried this but it wont work :

```
for (int i = 0; i <= 3; i++)
                    Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20, 20, 0, 0),
                      child: GestureDetector(
                        onLongPress: () => showDialog(
                          context: context,
                          builder: (BuildContext context) => AlertDialog(
                            title: Text("$i"),
                          ),
                        ),
```

I wanted to change the $i into specific name for specific photos.

Full code :

```
child: Row(
                children: [
                  for (int i = 0; i <= 3; i++)
                    Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20, 20, 0, 0),
                      child: GestureDetector(
                        onLongPress: () => showDialog(
                          context: context,
                          builder: (BuildContext context) => AlertDialog(
                            title: Text("$i"),
                          ),
                        ),
                        child: Card(
                          semanticContainer: true,
                          clipBehavior: Clip.antiAliasWithSaveLayer,
                          child: Container(
                            width: 300,
                            height: 300,
                            color: Colors.accents[i],
                            child: Image.asset(
                              "assets/farCryImages/$i.jpg",
                              alignment: Alignment.center,
                              fit: BoxFit.cover,
                            ),
                          ),
                          shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8),
                          ),
                          elevation: 5,
                        ),
                      ),
                    )
                ],
              ),
```

Any help is appreciated !!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure about your question. However, if you want to loop through different names for images, you should use a string list for their names:

```
List<String> imageName = [
    "first image",
    "second image", 
    // and so on
  ]
```

Then, call them in your loop:

```
     onLongPress: () => showDialog(
                          context: context,
                          builder: (BuildContext context) => AlertDialog(
                            title: Text(imageName[i]),
                          ),
                        ),
```

Also, for better solution, I suggest to use a class for each image:

```
class ImageItem{
  String name;
  String path;
  // and other parameters like id

  // and a constructor
}
```

Then create a list of this class and use them in  your loop.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, **Create a Stateful Widget class for the objects of interest** like so:

```
class CardObject extends StatefulWidget {
  final String title;
  final String image;
  final Color color;

  const CardObject(this.title, this.image, this.color);

  @override
  _CardObjectState createState() => _CardObjectState();
}

class _CardObjectState extends State<CardObject> {
  


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20, 20, 0, 0),
        child: GestureDetector(
          onLongPress: () => showDialog(
            context: context,
            builder: (BuildContext context) => AlertDialog(
              title: Text(widget.title),
            ),
          ),
          child: Card(
            semanticContainer: true,
            clipBehavior: Clip.antiAliasWithSaveLayer,
            child: Container(
              width: 300,
              height: 300,
              color: widget.color,
              child: Image.asset(
                "assets/farCryImages/${widget.image}",
                alignment: Alignment.center,
                fit: BoxFit.cover,
              ),
            ),
            shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8),
            ),
            elevation: 5,
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Then create a list to hold the CardObjects:

```
//List of CardObjects
  final List<CardObject> cardObjects = [
    CardObject('title 1', 'image1.jpg', Colors.red),
    CardObject('title 2', 'image2.jpg', Colors.blue),
    CardObject('title 3', 'image3.jpg', Colors.orange),
    CardObject('title 4', 'image4.jpg', Colors.grey),
  ];
```

Display your objects like this:

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: Row(
        children: cardObjects,
      ),
    );
  }
```